# Thread synchronization with Monitor.Pulse NOT working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have two methods, first() and second() and I assigned them to two threads.

Following are my second and first methods

```
     public void first()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(this);   

            Console.WriteLine("First");
            Monitor.Pulse(this);
        }
    }

    public void second()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            //Monitor.Wait(this);
            Console.WriteLine("Second");
            Monitor.Pulse(this);
        }
    }
```

The problem is on console only "Second" is getting printed.
Even though I have Monitor.Pulse() in second() to notify that the control should shift to first() but that aint happening.

I am following msdn following https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

Any help will be appreciated for info why the `s` thread is NOT shifting control to `f` thread with `Monitor.Pulse()` in second()

Follwinng is my Main()

```
        test t = new test();
        test1 t1 = new test1();
        Thread f = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t.first));
        Thread s = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t1.second));
        f.Start();
        s.Start();
        f.Join();
        s.Join();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The producer /consumer example works on one instance of cell. I think you should do the same. The reference to '`this`' is different for your 'first' and 'second'.

Comment: Even once this is fixed, there's still a race here, that `second` assumes that `first` acquired the lock and entered `Wait` before `second` acquires the lock. (because `Pulse` without anyone `Wait`ing gets discarded)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But this answer is working correctly.

Comment: @Alex - it will - *some* of the time. It's a race to see which thread actually manages to execute the `lock(this)` line first and is not *guaranteed*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How to fix it?

Comment: @Alex - that depends on what your actual problem/requirements are. Most of the fixes though are "ditch `Pulse`/`Wait` and use a more appropriate mechanism" - whether that be a different synchronization primitive or e.g. a thread-safe collection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that means that producer/consumer example on msdn will also work some times while not other times. is that right?

Comment: @Alex - no. That code *conditionally* calls `Wait` and uses the `readerFlag` to ensure it's operating correctly. You code has an unconditional `Wait` and not enough logic to guarantee to the thread calling `Wait` that another thread will call `Pulse` in the *future*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever should I accept this answer OR r you going to give all these details in ur answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Alex - you can accept it but be aware that just applying this fix has this race. If you want to avoid the race, we need more than just a toy example or more explanation of the work to be done by each thread, if you want to ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you initialize two instances of your `Test`-class (or you have two separate classes, `Test` and `Test1`), your usage of the `this`-keyword in the two methods refers to two separate objects.

Instead of locking on the context object, create a static object that's accessible to both methods, and lock on that:

```
public class Test
{
    static object _key = new object();

    public void First()
    {
        lock (_key)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(_key);
            Console.WriteLine("First");
            Monitor.Pulse(_key);
        }
    }

    public void Second()
    {
        lock (_key)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second");
            Monitor.Pulse(_key);
        }
    }
}
```

Put both `First()` and `Second()` in the same class, and create two instances of that class instead of one `Test` and one `Test1`, and you should see the results you expect, i.e. the output of the program will be

```
Second
First
```

EDIT: As [Damien points out though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343672/thread-synchronization-with-monitor-pulse-not-working-as-expected/39344512#comment66018919_39343929), this is not guaranteed to work either, since it assumes that `First()` is the first to acquire the lock.

Comment: You'll only see that output if `First` is *in fact* the first method to successfully acquire the `lock`, which is by no means guaranteed when you spin off two threads to execute these methods.